# What does the `Rebase and merge` merge strategy do on Bitbucket Server?

Tags: git-rebase, bitbucket-server, fast-forward

I was exploring the possible merge strategies on Bitbucket Server and one strategy caught my eye: "Rebase and merge" `rebase + merge --no-ff`

I understand that most of the debate about merge strategies revolves around rebase **vs** merge. This merge strategy seems to be rebase **and** merge. Is this correct? What advantages would this bring as opposed to only rebase or only merge?

Comment: Related question: [Semi linear merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714347/semi-linear-merge)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "rebase and merge" strategy is usually what people mean by "rebase". It just also indicates what happens next. When you use `--no-ff`, it makes a merge commit. Without it, you get a fast-forward so both refs would point to the same commit and it hides the fact that you had branched at all.

Merge `B` onto `A`:

```
A  *---*              A  *---*---*
    \       merge ->      \     /
B    *---*            B    *---*
```

Rebase `B` onto `A`:

```
A  *---*              A  *---*
    \      rebase ->          \
B    *---*            B        *---*
```

Rebase and merge (`--no-ff`) `B` onto `A`:

```
A  *---*              A  *---*                  A  *---*-------*
    \      rebase ->          \       merge ->          \     /
B    *---*            B        *---*   --no-ff  B        *---*
```

Rebase and merge (`--ff`) `B` onto `A`:

```
A  *---*              A  *---*                  A,B  *---*---*---*
    \      rebase ->          \       merge ->
B    *---*            B        *---*   --ff
```

Comment: So rebase with `--no-ff` allows me to have a (somewhat) cleaner history without losing the traceability branches provide?
I have always understood the "rebase" strategy to mean your last example. This clears thing up

Comment: You have understood that correctly. I'm glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket Server documentation says this for Rebase, merge  (rebase + merge --no-ff) AND Rebase, fast-forward (rebase + merge --ff-only) merge strategies.

"The PR branch is not modified by this operation"

As per this statement, in your example the commitSHA for the commits in branch B would remain unchanged. Bitbucket would assign new commitSHA for the same commits when applied in branch A.